# horizontal recyclerview swipe

Tags: android, recyclerview, swipe, horizontalscrollview

Есть горизонтальный `recyclerView` со списком элементов. Нужно сделать, чтобы при скролле последнего элемента появлялась кнопка "Показать больше" и открывался следующий фрагмент. Примерно как в [delivery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjLjl.jpg). Каким способом добиться такого эффекта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от того, насколько красиво вы хотите это сделать.

Подобной анимации можно добиться используя MotionLayout https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout или стороние библиотеки.

Без анимации я бы добавил еще один элемент (вашу кнопку "показать больше") в адаптер, с другим `ViewType`. Который по нажатию добавляет в адаптер новые элементы, становится `View.GONE` и вызывает `adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(lastOldIndex, lastNewIndex)`

Позже можно будет добавить анимацию на вашу кнопку, но эффект "прилипания" я бы делал с помощью MotionLayout